# Run forloop in yii model action create and save every record although forloop ends

Tags: php, yii

I need to run forloop in yii model action create or Addipblock()  and save every record although forloop end and then redirect it to view admin,

My first record take start from 1 and end 50, So in database should be 50 records added.

My code is like this:

```
`public function actionAddipblock(){        
    $model=new IpManager('addipblock'); 
    if(isset($_POST['IpManager'])){
        $model->attributes=$_POST['IpManager'];         
        $starting_ip = $_POST['IpManager']['starting_ip'];
        $ending_ip   = $_POST['IpManager']['ending_ip'];            
        if($model->validate('addipblock')){             
        for($ip = $starting_ip; $ip <= $ending_ip; $ip++){
            $model->ip = $ip;
            $model->server = $_POST['IpManager']['server'];
            $model->client = $_POST['IpManager']['client'];
            $model->status = $_POST['IpManager']['status'];
            $model->creation_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }           
        if($model->save()){ 
               $this->redirect(array('admin'));     
         }
          else{
                echo 'Error:';
            }               
        }
    }
    $this->render('addipblock',array('model'=>$model));
}`
```

But when I run this code it save only one record not save all recorde until forloop end.
Guys what will you suggest me for this? what should I can do for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this inside you forloop,

```
    for($ip = $starting_ip; $ip <= $ending_ip; $ip++){
    // you need to null your model primary key
    $model->id = null; // like this
    $model->ip = $ip;
    $model->server = $_POST['IpManager']['server'];
    $model->client = $_POST['IpManager']['client'];
    $model->status = $_POST['IpManager']['status'];
    $model->creation_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $model->isNewRecord = true;
    $model->save();
```

}

Comment: How to redirect admin page?

Comment: You are already use redirect in your method after for loop as 
    `if($model->save()){ 
               $this->redirect(array('admin'));     
         }`

Comment: +1 Shahzad... Your answer helped me a lot. I was stuck due to this problem from very long. THanks a lot .